# Determining chance level for binary classification for given sample size

Tags: statistics

I am aware that "chance level" - the percent classification accuracy which you should get when you are assigning binary labels to your datasamples just randomly - is theoretically 50%. For big datasets that is - for smaller datasets it is possible to achieve higher accuracies (for instance the dataset might not be as representative). Is there a way to calculate for a given dataset and size of dataset its empirical chance level?

Many thanks,
Pegah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question: I think by using the binomial distribution we can calculate for a given size of the dataset the chance level - see 2.2. Statistical significance of classification using a binomial
cumulative distribution - in the following publication by Combrisson & Jerbi: [Assessment of decoding accuracy](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Karim_Jerbi/publication/271022735_Exceeding_chance_level_by_chance_The_caveat_of_theoretical_chance_levels_in_brain_signal_classification_and_statistical_assessment_of_decoding_accuracy/links/54db795c0cf261ce15d02d9e.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you have prior information that the categories are not equally likely, then yes--otherwise no.  For instance, if you know that the prior probability of category $\omega_1$ is (say) $P(\omega_1) = 0.6$, then you should always guess category $\omega_1$ and you'll be right $0.6$ of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) would be the tool that you are looking for. If you know the true labels, you can calculate, for a set of decision rules, their "sensitivity" levels (which is the true positive rate), and their $1-$specificity levels, which is the true negative rate. Then taking the $\sup$ of (sensitivity + specificity) over the set of your rules, would give you the [best](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic) decision rule. Basically, when you have 
$$
\text{sensitivity} +  \text{specificity} =1,
$$
it means that you have exactly $50\%$ true positive assignments and $50\%$ true negative assignments. Namely, a pure chance level w.r.t  to the "positives" signs and the "negatives" signs, or formaly
$$
P("+"|"+")=P("-"|"-")=1/2.
$$

Comment: Isn't this like saying that you would take the classifier (/decision rule) with the highest accuracy, given that I have binary classification and my classes are balanced? I think this is not exactly my question, as I am more interested in the properties of the dataset.